# Simple If-Else concept of Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

Why is the following code resulting in just True? Shouldn't the output be something like this:

```
True
False
```

because there's no else statement. So once it verifies and executes the if command, shouldn't it read the`return False` command as well? This command is not within the `If` indentation and it's not even mentioned with `else`.

```
def is_even(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return True
    return False
    
print(is_even(2))
```

Comment: No, because returning immediately exits the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing 'return' terminates function execution immediately, with the specified value as the value of the function call.

It does not mean something like 'add this to what is to be returned at some  future time, meanwhile carry on execution', which is what would be needed for your apparently understanding.

This is how 'return' works in most procedural languages.

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement is used to return a value to the caller and exit a function. A function will stop immediately and return a value if it meets with `return` statement.
Also note that `if` statement does not requires `else` clause every time. It can stay alone to handle specific cases.
As an example:

```
x = 44

if x>46:
    print("hello")
print("hi")
```